# Is there a way to prettify name of detail_route when using url_path?

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

Project makes use of Django REST Framework. Here is one of detail views:

```
    @detail_route(methods=['POST'], 
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated], 
    url_path="invite/(?P<member_id>[^/.]+)")

    def invite_member(self, request, pk=None, member_id=None):
        ...
```

When opening browser i see that this url specified as follows:

```
^api/ ^deal/ ^ ^deals/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/invite/(?P<member_id>[^/.]+)/$ [name='deal-invite/(?P<member-id>[^/.]+)']
```

As you can see name for this view looks awfully - is there a way to make it prettier?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the default name generated for your custom action, you can use the `url_name` parameter to customize it.

For example, if you want to change the name of our custom action to 'user-change-password', you could write:

```
from myapp.permissions import IsAdminOrIsSelf
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route

class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @detail_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=[IsAdminOrIsSelf], url_name='change-password')
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
```